# Counting number of notes in Google Keep

Tags: google, google-keep

I wonder if there is a way to display the number of notes in Google Keep.

For programmers, this would be similar to a

"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table"

in SQL.

Is there a way to digit some special keywords in the search box, to display this?

Thanks.